# Errors in build -- missing references

Tags: .net, dll, build, namespaces, reference

I can't build because of some .dll's not being able to be resolved. Here is the "warning" for one of the main ones, the error is just the basic "Type or namespace..." error.

Does anyone know what this means or how to fix it?

Warning 6   The primary reference "C:\SVN\k2\PandaTrunk\Teapot\Chatham.Panda.Teapot.Controls\bin\Debug\Chatham.Panda.Teapot.Controls.dll" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v3.5". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "C:\SVN\k2\PandaTrunk\Teapot\Chatham.Panda.Teapot.Controls\bin\Debug\Chatham.Panda.Teapot.Controls.dll" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35". Chatham.Panda.Teapot.Models.FxForward

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are building project to .NET Framework version less than 3.5. Check if your project is targeting at least .NET Framework 3.5.

**EDIT:**
If it doesn't work then download [Microsoft Chart Controls for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=130F7986-BF49-4FE5-9CA8-910AE6EA442C&displaylang=en) and make sure that requested DLL is in the GAC.

Comment: It's referencing chart controls fine.

Comment: That's not what the warning message says.  Add the assembly to your References node to flush this out.